# Renaming a range from files w/Powershell

Tags: powershell

I got some help with this question

[Renaming a range from files w/Powershell - from first to third from last hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52884866/renaming-a-range-from-files-w-powershell-from-first-to-third-from-last-hyphen)

and it worked wonderfully, but now I have a new problem.

My csv file names now have random numbers of hyphens like so:

```
abc-def-ghi-jkl-mno-pqr-s-tuv-ke-traffic-by-domains-17-Oct-2018_23-49-38-6d73395f476ad09a7506dc00533933b8.csv
abc-def-ghi-jkl-ke-traffic-by-domains-15-Oct-2018_05-20-36-75eabae7c4123198ff5fe6f4f642449f.csv
abc-def-ghi-jkl-mno--ke-traffic-by-domains-12-Oct-2018_06-23-58-b13eb8f362c09fbe405458fac8af8f8e.csv
```

The number of hyphens change from file to file.

I would like to rename them with powershell to

```
abc-17-Oct-2018.csv
abc-15-Oct-2018.csv
abc-12-Oct-2018.csv
```

I tried the following:

1.Delete everything after "_"

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv | Foreach-Object -Process { 
    $NewName = [Regex]::Match($_.Name,"^[^_]*").Value + '.csv'
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
}
```

2.Delete everything after the first "-" until "ke-traffic-by-domains-"

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv | Rename-Item -NewName { 
$word = "-*ke-traffic-by-domains-"
$NewName = $_.Name -split $word + '.csv' 
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
}
```

But I'm stuck on No.2 deleting a range with regular expression.

Can someone kindly show me a way to change the file names?

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression to match your criteria (see [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jmGZVB/1))

```
Get-ChildItem *.csv |
  Where-Object Name -match '^([^\-]+)-.*?-traffic-by-domains-(\d{1,2}-\D{3}-20\d{2})_'|
    Rename-Item -NewName {"{0}-{1}.csv" -f $Matches[1],$Matches[2]} -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`

Files on my Ramdrive after running the script over your sample csv names:

```
> gci

    Verzeichnis: A:\

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-11-05     09:38              0 abc-12-Oct-2018.csv
-a----       2018-11-05     09:38              0 abc-15-Oct-2018.csv
-a----       2018-11-05     09:38              0 abc-17-Oct-2018.csv
```

Comment: Thank you, I just started learning about regex and this helped a lot. However your answer doesn't seem to move even when I remove the -WhatIf.

Comment: Can somebody please help me understand this answer?
I'm not sure what the "-f $Matches[1],$Matches[2]" part means, plus powershell doesn't do anything with this command.

Comment: Did you remove the `-WhatIf` after checking the output? I tested here successfully. The `-match` operator fills the `$Matches` variable, the (capture groups) from the REgEx can be accessed by index - $Matches[0] being the whole RegEx. The `-f = format operator` is explained [here](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html)